# How to remove flex in CSS

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am facing a problem in the alignment of two created grids in HTML.
I created Grids using bootstrap.
Below is the code for the

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>IRIS Flower Classification</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h2 class="heading">
        IRIS Flower Classification
    </h2>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col1">
        <form action="{{url_for('predict') }}" method=post>
            <label type="text" for="Sepal_length">Sepal length:</label>
            <input type="number" id="sepal_length" name="sepal_length" step=".1" value=""><br>
            <label type="text" for="Sepal width">Sepal width:</label>
            <input type="number" id="sepal width" name="sepal width" step=".1" value=""><br>
            <label type="text" for="Petal length">Petal length:</label>
            <input type="number" id="Petal length" name="petal length" step=".1" value=""><br>
            <label type="text" for="Petal width">Petal width:</label>
            <input type="number" id="Petal width" name="Petal width" step=".1" value=""><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Predict">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
        <h2 class="testdata">
            Sample test data
        </h2>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Species</th>
                <th>Sepal length</th>
                <th>Sepal width</th>
                <th>Petal length</th>
                <th>Petal width</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Setosa</td>
                <td>5.4</td>
                <td>3.9</td>
                <td>1.7</td>
                <td>0.4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Versicolor</td>
                <td>6.2</td>
                <td>2.2</td>
                <td>4.5</td>
                <td>1.5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Virginica</td>
                <td>5.7</td>
                <td>2.5</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


 <br>
    <div class="output">
        <img height="241px" width="203px" src="/static/img/{{ prediction_answer }}.png" alt="No Prediction">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting output as below[flex image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZUwX.jpg)

it is difficult for me to align both columns.
Can anyone tell me how can we create a column of a particular pixel in HTML?
Can anyone tell me how to remove flex?

Comment: Since you're using bootstrap, you should use the column system to decide how much width each column gets. For instance, create 2 columns of 6 with `col-md-6` classes.

Comment: Change `col1` to say `col-md-4` and `col2` to `col-md-8`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use grid system of bootstrap

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>IRIS Flower Classification</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

 <h2 class="heading text-center">
        IRIS Flower Classification
 </h2>
 
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <form action="{{url_for('predict') }}" method=post class="row">
            <label type="text" for="Sepal_length" class="col-6">Sepal length:</label>
            <input type="number" id="sepal_length" name="sepal_length" step=".1" value="" class="col-6 pull-right"><br>
            <label type="text" for="Sepal width" class="col-6">Sepal width:</label>
            <input type="number" id="sepal width" name="sepal width" step=".1" value="" class="col-6 pull-right"><br>
            <label type="text" for="Petal length" class="col-6">Petal length:</label>
            <input type="number" id="Petal length" name="petal length" step=".1" value="" class="col-6 pull-right"><br>
            <label type="text" for="Petal width" class="col-6">Petal width:</label>
            <input type="number" id="Petal width" name="Petal width" step=".1" value="" class="col-6 pull-right"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Predict">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <h2 class="testdata">
            Sample test data
        </h2>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Species</th>
                <th>Sepal length</th>
                <th>Sepal width</th>
                <th>Petal length</th>
                <th>Petal width</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Setosa</td>
                <td>5.4</td>
                <td>3.9</td>
                <td>1.7</td>
                <td>0.4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Versicolor</td>
                <td>6.2</td>
                <td>2.2</td>
                <td>4.5</td>
                <td>1.5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Virginica</td>
                <td>5.7</td>
                <td>2.5</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


 <br>
    <div class="output">
        <img height="241px" width="203px" src="/static/img/{{ prediction_answer }}.png" alt="No Prediction">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```